# plm model in R, "Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed"

Tags: r, plm

Here is data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dEkCfGUAhbCUr34FXeHjK8YhZ3j0yXTo/view?usp=sharing

This is my code:

[image]

```
library(plm)
page1.p <- pdata.frame(page1, index = c("tract", "YearBuilt"))
fm <- plm(log_salesprice ~ firstc0+firstc1+firstc2+firstc3+firstc4+firstc5+firstc0+
          firstcneg5p+firstcneg4+firstcneg3+firstcneg2+firstcneg1, data=page1.p, 
          model = "random")
```

The error:

> Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Comment: There are a few posts that address this issue--[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510067/fixed-effects-plm-package-r-multiple-observations-per-year-id) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869101/problems-with-plm-duplicate-time-ids-error), for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed Effects plm package R - multiple observations per year/id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510067/fixed-effects-plm-package-r-multiple-observations-per-year-id)